# VBA Check if a cell value is part of an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Can somebody help on how to test if the value of the cell is part of a list?
I have tried several things but nothing worked out :(

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("E4:E104")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Dim FI As Variant
FI = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5").Value


With Target.Offset(0, -4)
.Value = Date
.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"
End With

With Target.Offset(0, 5)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-3]-RC[-2]"
End With

If Target = FI Then
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = False
    Target.Offset(0, 3).Locked = True
ElseIf Target <> FI Then
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Locked = True
    Target.Offset(0, 3).Locked = False
End If
```

what do I have to add to see if the value f the cell is equal to one of the values of cells A1 to A5?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use this the function below to check if a value is in an array:

```
Function CheckInArray(SearchVal As Variant, TestArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim icount As Long

    For icount = LBound(TestArray) To UBound(TestArray)

        If TestArray(icount, 1) = SearchVal Then

            CheckInArray = True
            Exit Function

        End If

    Next icount

    CheckInArray = False

End Function
```

The function returns `True` if your `SearchVal` is in the array, `False` if it isn't.
You could add a line like:

```
If CheckInArray(Target.value, FI) then
```

Comment: it returns an error message telling that the sub statement is missing. is it because it is a worksheet change private sub?

Comment: @user12408889: I'm not sure what causes that error, it works for me. Are you sure you've not added the function to the sub? it should be below the `End Sub` statement or in a different module.